# IIS - Changing binding from one site to another without downtime

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, iis-7

I am attempting to use ServerManager from a C# console application to make some site changes to the IIS metabase.

I have a site I want to deploy without any downtime, to do this I am:

1. Creating a new second site with it's own application pool using the new DLLs
2. Adding a binding which can be accessed locally so I can fire the first request into the second site and it's "warmed up"
3. I am removing the binding of www.domain.com from the original site, and then adding it to the second site, then calling CommitChanges()

Here is where the trouble starts, the binding information is correctly updated, however IIS has stopped the second site. Is there some way I can remove the original binding and place it on a new site without calling commit changes twice?

I really want to avoid having the overhead of ARR in this instance or any other load balancing etc, is there a way of swapping a binding from one site to another without downtime? It really feels like there should be.

Comment: i think the only way to sensibly do this kind of re-routing is to do it at the firewall/gateway/TMG box in your network and have both site hot with local urls.

Comment: Luke - completely agree on architecture - just asking to see if there is a way of doing this, if I can have no downtime on the actual box and not need to touch anything, well that's a good thing! :)

Comment: No downtime on the actual box?  How about requests being processed at the time of the binding switch?  I think the only way to do this is to load balance and properly drain stop the box before switching.

Comment: Without going off topic, the other old app is still there and running, any requests before the change should go there and get processed, any new requests will goto the new app. Having requests go into the either by not having an active binding is exactly what I am trying to avoid :)

Comment: I think the point me and @dtryon are trying to make is that a live switch between two sites on the same machine is not supported (even the implementation of such a thing when writing a webserver would be non-trivial). In the microsoft stack this scenario is instead supported by an ISA role server

Comment: Thanks Luke - appreciate the feedback - I'll rephrase the question to focus a little bit more on the what than the why, as even if there is downtime the new legitimate config is causing one of the sites to stop.

Comment: Thank again guys, after a little extra thought I decided to throw some effort behind ARR as a reverse proxy in front of the two sites, now they can have different bindings. The swap script uses make unavailable gracefully and waits for the current requests to drain before deleting the original site. 

http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/11/09/using-arr-config-extensibility-to-gracefully-stop-server.aspx

Comment: if Microsoft doesn't support this with IIS, you'll be happy to know that you can do this with nginx: http://developer.7digital.com/blog/atomic-mono-deployment-capistrano-and-nginx-under-debian

Comment: I tried this myself and if I have to sites, it works when switching from one to the other but not in the reverse order. I think that when I do `CommitChanges()`, it writes the changes out to the config and incrementally validates it instead of treating the whole change as a transaction. So if it happens to write out the changes as first removing the bindings and adding new ones, it works, but if it happens to try to add the new bindings before removing the old ones, it stops one of the sites because they both exist with the same bindings in the config before the changes are committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Microsoft doesn't support this with IIS, you'll be happy to know that you can do this with nginx: http://developer.7digital.com/blog/atomic-mono-deployment-capistrano-and-nginx-under-debian

Comment: so strange, this is the second time I've been to the 7digital site today! Turns out ARR was a good solution for a time, but I'm moving to FastCGI + Owin + Nginx. Thank you for re-affirming the decision!